# .htaccess redirecting non-existing file to index.php in folder with filename as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/app/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

In the past this worked great to redirect from:

*website.com/app/whatever*

to

*website.com/app/index.html?view=whatever*

Now due to our new testing structure the web application will move to dynamic folders, for example:

*website.com/aaa/bbb/app/whatever*

and the RewriteRule I have in place **does not** redirect this correctly to

*website.com/aaa/bbb/app/index.html?view=whatever*

I also have the following folder structure:

```
root
- app
-- index.php
-- .htaccess

- folder1
-- index.php
-- .htaccess

-index.php
-.htaccess
```

The .htaccess files in the subfolder are all basically doing the same, just the "/app/" is replaced by, for example, "folder1". There might be a better way of doing this all in one htaccess.

Comment: That rule will certainly never rewrite anything to `index.html`, but only to `index.php`.

Comment: Take a look at your `RewriteBase` directive. This certainly won't work with dynamic folders the way you describe. You could rewrite to an absolute path of the index file instead.

Comment: @arkascha the html is obviously a mistake :D - but you solved the issue for me! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to arkascha I found the issue.

I was blind to the path in the Rewrite base.

This works:

```
RewriteBase /f1/f2/app/
```

Comment: With "dynamic folders" I understood that this prefix may vary, for example for different sites you operate. If so then a static `RewriteBase` won't work. Instead you can simply rewrite to an absolute path. Something like that: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ /$1/index.php?view=$2 [END]`. Then no `RewriteBase` is required at all.